# Exponents in $\mathbf{Sets}^{G^{{\rm op}}}$ for an arbitrary group $G$.

Tags: category-theory, monoid, adjoint-functors, topos-theory

This is **Exercise I.5(b)** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]."* According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cmathbf%7BSets%7D%5E%7BG%5E%7B%5Crm%20op%7D%7D%24%2C%20monoid%2C%20group%2C%20exponent%2C%20category&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

From p. 17 *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 1:** Given two functors
>
> $$F:\mathbf{X}\to \mathbf{A}\quad G: \mathbf{A}\to \mathbf{X},$$
>
> we say that $G$ is *right adjoint* to $F$, written $F\dashv G$, when for any $X\in{\rm Ob}(\mathbf{X})$ and any $A\in{\rm Ob}(\mathbf{A})$, there is a natural bijection between morphisms
>
> $$\frac{X\stackrel{f}{\to}G(A)}{F(X)\stackrel{h}{\to}A},$$
>
> in the sense that each $f$, as displayed, uniquely determines $h$, and conversely.

From p. 19 *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 2:** Suppose products exist in $\mathbf{C}$. For a fixed $A\in{\rm Ob}(\mathbf{C})$, one may consider the functor
>
> $$A\times -: \mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}.$$
>
> If this functor had a right adjoint (unique up to isomorphism), this adjoint is denoted  by
>
> $$(-)^A:\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}.$$
>
> In this case $A$ is said to be an *exponentiable* object of $\mathbf{C}$.

### The Question:

> For objects $X, Y$ in $\mathbf{Sets}^{G^{{\rm op}}}$, for $G$ a group, show that the exponent $Y^X$ can be described as the set of all functions $f: X\to Y$, with the right action of $g\in G$ on such a function defined by $(fg)x=[f(xg^{-1})]g$ for $x\in X$.

### Thoughts:

I've answered **Exercise I.5(a)** with the help of Goldblatt's, *"Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic,"* since **$\S$4.6(Exponentiation)** defines exponentiation for *left action* by a monoid $M$.

Here is **Exercise I.5(a)**:

> In $\mathbf{B}M=\mathbf{Sets}^{M^{{\rm op}}}$ for $M$ a monoid observe that an object $X$ is a right action $X\times M\to X$ of $M$ on a set $X$ and that, $Y$ being another object, ${\rm Hom}(X, Y)$ is the set of equivariant maps $e:X\to Y$ [maps with $e(xm)=(ex)m$ for all $x\in X, m\in M$]. Prove that the exponent $Y^X$ is the set ${\rm Hom}(M\times X, Y)$ of equivariant maps $e: M\times X\to Y$, where $M$ is the set $M$ with right action by $M$, with the action $e\mapsto ek$ of $k\in M$ on $e$ defined by $(ek)(g, x)=e(kg, x)$.

Here is [**$\S$4.6(Exponentiation)**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AprOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=goldblatt+%22our+initial+motivation+showed+that%22&source=bl&ots=AV2oVD5ZnQ&sig=ACfU3U3UEpi2NgPLRLA7oQgZfKvSpqSvwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifn9vWhsXnAhXDuHEKHfcPCy8Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=goldblatt%20%22our%20initial%20motivation%20showed%20that%22&f=false).

It's not too difficult to translate the description therein of the exponent.

### Context:

For a rough idea of my abilities, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3535706/104041) of mine. I am self-taught in category theory.

I think, given more time, that I should be able to do the exercise. But I've given it a couple of days and have got nowhere. I would like to move on to the next question.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try to prove that when $M$ is a group, then $\hom_{M-\mathbf{Set}}(M\times X,Y) \cong \hom_\mathbf{Set}(X,Y)$ and that under this isomorphism, the action given in I.5.(a) becomes the action described in the question (b) ?

Consider $$\begin{align}
f: M\times X&\to M\times X,\\
 (m,x)&\mapsto (m,xm^{-1}).
\end{align}$$

Then $$\begin{align}
f((m,x)\cdot_{M\times X} n) &= f(mn,xn) \\
&= (mn, xm^{-1}) \\
&= (m,xm^{-1})\cdot_{M\times X^{triv}} n\\
& = f(m,x)\cdot_{M\times X^{triv}} n,
\end{align}$$ where $X^{triv}$ is $X$ with the trivial $M$-action.

It follows clearly that $M\times X\cong M\times X^{triv}$ as $M$-sets, so $\hom_{M-\mathbf{Set}}(M\times X,Y) \cong \hom_{M-\mathbf{Set}}(M\times X^{triv},Y) \cong \hom_\mathbf{Set}(X,Y)$ (the last isomorphism is easy to prove, and it's a good exercise)

Now you only have to see what the action on the left you described in (a) becomes on the right. It should be the action described in (b).